# How to create a shapefile or gml from a Oracle database using SDE.ST_Geometry?

Tags: python, shapefile, oracle-dbms, gml, st-geometry

I have a ORACLE database 10g(Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0) with a SDE.ST_Geometry field and i want to make a program in python so i can create several shapefiles based on this ST_Geometry field and use other fields as well so i can fill my shapes with attributes.
I only have database access and i have no idea which arcgis is related.

How can i do this? Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Please update the question to specify the exact Oracle release and the version of ArcGIS which created the ST_GEOMETRY.  Has the listener been correctly configured to permit SDE.ST_AsText invocation from SQL*Plus? Do you have the rest of ArcGIS available? What Python libraries for shapefile manipulation do you have available?

Comment: @Vince i'm not using nothing, im starting from scratch. I have no idea how to do this so i'm asking for suggestion how to start this. Where to look at.. At this moment i'm looking for GDAL libs.However i follow your advice by updating my question.

Comment: There's likely scores of shapefile and/or GML access libraries, dozens of them written in Python.  As it stands, your question is *very* broad, and not particularly answerable.

Comment: @Vince, my question is pretty simple if you have some experience on my issue, which is how to export/create a shapefile from a oracle database base on the field sde.st_geommetry, to shapefile or gml, please help me. If you know dozens of libs that allows me to do this, i just want to know at least one example of that dozens libs that you've experience, so i can investigate? I just need suggestions to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same issue
GDAL can be a good aproach..

Please take a look on

http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_oci.html

```
import cx_Oracle
# Import osgeo
    try:
        from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal
        print "Import success!"
    except:
        sys.exit('ERROR: cannot find GDAL/OGR modules')

# To connect to oracle database you will need:
     Connection_String = 'username/pwd@ (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xx.xxx.xxx.xx)(PORT = xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = name.service)))'   
    cx_Oracle.connect(Connection_String)


    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("select shape.minx, shape.miny, somefield from mydbase.table")

# "shape" is the name of your SDE.ST_Geometry field.
```

finally you just have to follow this link:

http://www.digital-geography.com/create-and-edit-shapefiles-with-python-only/#.VDPnvPldU31

and problem solved.. If you have this same issue and find this question useful, please vote.

Comment: Could you add the final lines  with SDO driver?